# How can I store Id in a set of type ID from an object?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

```java
@isTest
static void test_getBankDetailsFinnone(){
           
    Bank_Detail__c bankDetails = [Select Id from Bank_Detail__c limit 1];
    Set<ID> bd = new Set<ID>();
    bd.add(bankDetails);
    CF_UW_DataProvider.getBankDetailsFinnone(bd);
           
}
```

I wish to store Id from object  Bank_Detail__c in set  bd and then call a method getBankDetailsFinnone which takes argument as a set of type id. I am getting errors with it.  Can someone please help me?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Will be helpful if you mention that too.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, Change this line

```
bd.add(bankDetails);
```

to

```
bd.add(bankDetails.Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one statement

```
CF_UW_DataProvider.getBankDetailsFinnone(new Map<Id,Bank_Detail__c> (
     [SELECT Id FROM Bank_Detail__c]).keySet());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```java
Bank_Detail__c bankDetails = [Select Id from Bank_Detail__c limit 1];
    
Set<ID> bd = new Set<ID>();
bd.add(bankDetails.Id);
CF_UW_DataProvider.getBankDetailsFinnone(bd);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is because you are trying to reference an object of "Bank_Detail__c" to a set of type Id.
In the code block please make the following changes in your code:

```
Bank_Detail__c bankDetails = [Select Id from Bank_Detail__c limit 1];
Set<ID> bd = new Set<ID>();
bd.add(bankDetails.Id);
CF_UW_DataProvider.getBankDetailsFinnone(bd);
```

Hope this explanation will resolve your query.

Thanks

Akshay